# ListBoxItem ControlTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to set a ControlTemplate to the ListBoxItem control, right now I haven't made any modification, it's as it comes out of the box:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem"
                 x:Key="listBoxItemCustomTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
            Name="Bd"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected">
                    <Condition.Value>
                        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                    </Condition.Value>
                </Condition>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive">
                    <Condition.Value>
                        <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                    </Condition.Value>
                </Condition>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works fine, the problem is when I try to use an ItemTemplateSelector in my ListBox. The DataTemplateSelector code doesn't even run, apparently there's something preventing the ItemTemplateSelector from working in that ControlTemplate, but I'm not sure how.

This is the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource ExperimentExplorerTemplateSelector}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource customListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

And the style that sets the ControlTempalte:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="customListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource listBoxItemCustomTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you used ShowMeTheTemplate and this does not always work correctly.

Here is the `ListBoxItem` template's `ContentPresenter` from ShowMeTheTemplate (Aero):

```
<ContentPresenter
    Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
```

and the same section from Blend:

```
<ContentPresenter
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

and there are other differences as well but this line specifically:

```
    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
```

is what is the cause of your `DataTemplateSelector` being bypassed.  I can't say that I understand why because `ContentStringFormat` is supposed to be ignored if `TemplateSelector` is set.

The moral is that we need a more reliable way to extract the same templates/styles that Blend extracts.

Comment: nice! it worked, I spent some good 3 ~ 4 trying to figure it out. Thank you!